# Missing expression inside sub-query statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I am using the infamous "CityJail" schema to answer a question "List the names of all criminals who have committed more than average number of crimes and aren’t listed as violent offenders."

Here is my code:

```
SELECT first, last 
FROM criminals NATURAL JOIN
crimes
GROUP BY first, last
HAVING COUNT(*) > (SELECT AVG(COUNT(DISTINCT crime_id))
FROM crimes)
AND (SELECT v_status = 'N' FROM crimes)
GROUP BY first, last
);
```

but I get an error:

> ORA-00936: missing expression
> 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
> *Cause:
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 7 Column: 22

When I change my code to:

```
SELECT first, last 
FROM criminals NATURAL JOIN
crimes
GROUP BY first, last
HAVING COUNT(*) > (SELECT AVG(COUNT(DISTINCT crime_id))
FROM crimes)
AND v_status = 'N'
GROUP BY first, last
);
```

I get an error:

> ORA-01787: only one clause allowed per query block
> 01787. 00000 -  "only one clause allowed per query block"
> *Cause:
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 8 Column: 1

What am I doing wrong?

criminals:

```
Name        Null?    Type         
----------- -------- ------------ 
CRIMINAL_ID NOT NULL NUMBER(6)    
LAST                 VARCHAR2(15) 
FIRST                VARCHAR2(10) 
STREET               VARCHAR2(30) 
CITY                 VARCHAR2(20) 
STATE                CHAR(2)      
ZIP                  CHAR(5)      
PHONE                CHAR(10)     
V_STATUS             CHAR(1)      
P_STATUS             CHAR(1)
```

crimes:

```
Name            Null?    Type      
--------------- -------- --------- 
CRIME_ID        NOT NULL NUMBER(9) 
CRIMINAL_ID     NOT NULL NUMBER(6) 
CLASSIFICATION           CHAR(1)   
DATE_CHARGED             DATE      
STATUS                   CHAR(2)   
HEARING_DATE             DATE      
APPEAL_CUT_DATE          DATE      
DATE_RECORDED            DATE
```

Comment: Syntactically, It looks like you have incorrectly placed closing parenthesis, ), on this line, `FROM crimes)`. You can just remove it.

Comment: I've tried and it's the same with the parenthesis and without. If you are talking about line 6, it cases "Missing right parenthesis" error.

Comment: why you use `DISTINCT crime_id` ? can this be shared between different `criminal_id` ?

Comment: Changing crime_ID to criminal_ID doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fix Your Scalar Subquery in the Having Clause**

```
  SELECT first
      , last
   FROM criminals cls
NATURAL
   JOIN crimes 
  WHERE v_status = 'N'
  GROUP BY first
      , last
 HAVING COUNT(1) >(
         SELECT AVG(COUNT(DISTINCT crime_id))
   FROM crimes
   GROUP BY criminal_id);
```

The scalar query is malformed in both of your attempts.

I moved the condition `WHERE v_status = 'N'` to the main query (you are only concerned about criminal whom are non-violent).

Comment: Thanks, but your code gives an error: "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 5"

Comment: @GregNog this is fixed

Comment: I copied your code exactly. "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 12 Column: 13"

Comment: @GregNog corrected the use of v_status in the subquery